# UINavigationBar backgroundColor not working with UITabBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

I'm using UINavigationController and set the background color in didFinishLaunching...:

self.navController.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

It works nicely in the first view controller as seen in the first image. In the second view controller (just pushed using segue from the button) I have an UITabBar (no UITabBarController) and there the background color does not work. If i remove the UITabBar it works.

[Correct navigation bar background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhWwr.png)

[Wrong navigation bar background color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxqR8.png)

The project contains no other code what so ever. It works if I use barTintColor instead of backgroundColor, but I don't think that looks as good.

Anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Please Update your question with what code you use for change bartintcolor

Answer (score 0):

you have to set property TintColor for background color of navigation bar

in Objective-c

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

In swift

`navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()`

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.GreenColor()
```

or

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .blackColor()
```

Or

```
[navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use barTintColor property like so:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.green
```

Comment: barTintColor doesn't actually print the correct color, well only a tint. How can I set the precise, desired color to the tabbar? Any idea? (I don't want to use image for background as I'd like to set it dynamically)

Comment: Ok you actually need to set `barTintColor` and `isTranslucent = false` ...